# Python: Epoch Time Converter Minus 'x' Days

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to take in an epoch timestamp in milliseconds and return the same timestamp minus x amount of days.

```
def epoch_unseen_time(epoch, days_unseen=globals.DAYS_UNSEEN):
    timestamp = epoch / 1000
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days_unseen)
    dt_minus_days = dt - delta
    epoch_minus_days = int(dt_minus_days.timestamp()) * 1000

    return epoch_minus_days
```

Currently the amount of days I have `globals.DAYS_UNSEEN` set is 90. This is to do a comparison later to see if a devices last audit time (outputted in epoch milliseconds) is greater than 90 days.

This is the logic that sees if the last audit time has been longer than 90 days.

```
            if "devices" in parsed_data:
            data = parsed_data["devices"]
            for item in data:
                if item.get("online", "N/A") == False:
                    last_audit = item.get("lastAuditDate", "N/A")
                    epoch_days_unseen = epoch_unseen_time(last_audit)
                    if last_audit > epoch_days_unseen:
                        unseen_devices_id.append(id)
```

Currently, the output from this is not as expected. I am getting devices added to the unseen_devices_id list that aren't more than the 90 days. I am thinking that this is to do with the epoch_unseen_time() function not outputting correctly. I have been messing with this and seem to be making it worse. Any ideas or inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally go this working. Changed the epoch function to return the amount of days and then in the comparison compared the out put to globals.DAYS_UNSEEN

```
def epoch_days_unseen():
        epoch_timestamp_seconds = epoch_timestamp_ms / 1000
        current_timestamp_seconds = time.time()
        time_difference_seconds = current_timestamp_seconds - epoch_timestamp_seconds
        days_ago = time_difference_seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)

        return days_ago
```

So far this seems to be working for me.